# setting value of selectlist item with no value breaks submit event handler

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Such a strange problem as I don't get any console errors.

I have a enum dropdownlist which is rendered like this:

```
 @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(x => x.FixtureState,"-- All change requests states--", new { @class = "form-control " })
```

and the html is rendered thus:

```
<select class="form-control  input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-required="The FixtureState field is required." id="FixtureState" name="FixtureState"><option value="">-- All change requests states--</option>
<option selected="selected" value="0">Draft</option>
<option value="1">Change eequested</option>
<option value="2">Change accepted</option>
<option value="3">Change declined</option>
</select>
```

Then I have a script which calls this line:

```
 $('#FixtureState').val('');
```

After which I call this line to submit the form that fixturestate is in:

```
 $('#getfixturesform').submit();
```

When `$('#FixtureState').val('');` is enabled the submit function does not fire, when I comment it out, the submit works fine. I am at a loss what could be going on here. As I say there aren't any console errors.

**edit**: just tried setting the fixture state to ('1') instead of ('') and it works.  I don't follow how setting it to ('')  breaks it.

**edit2**: changing it to `$('#FixtureState').val('-- All change requests states--');` fixes the problem, but I would still like to understand how setting it to ('') breaks a submit handler and nothing else.

Comment: If the property is annotated with the Required attribute, then setting the value to a "blank" value means it's invalid. If you also have unobtrusive validation enabled, then _that_ prevents the form submission when any field fails validation.

Comment: It's not required, but I believe unobtrusive validation is loaded on this page so I think you have found the problem. Thanks!

Comment: It is required (and `enum` cannot be `null`, and you can see that the `data-val-required` attribute is present)